# Python read csv by column (header) dynamically with hash key

Tags: python, csv, header, dynamically-generated

I try to read vertically a csv file as follow to insert in graphite/carbon timeseries DB with python.

```
"No.","time","00:00:00","00:00:01","00:00:02","00:00:03","00:00:04","00:00:05","00:00:06","00:00:07","00:00:08","00:00:09","00:00:0A"
"1","2021/09/12 02:16",235,610,345,997,446,130,129,94,555,274,4
"2","2021/09/12 02:17",364,210,371,341,294,87,179,106,425,262,3
"3","2021/09/12 02:18",297,343,860,216,275,81,73,113,566,274,3
"4","2021/09/12 02:19",305,243,448,262,387,64,63,119,633,249,3
"5","2021/09/12 02:20",276,151,164,263,315,86,92,175,591,291,1
"6","2021/09/12 02:21",264,343,287,542,312,83,72,122,630,273,4
"7","2021/09/12 02:22",373,157,266,446,246,90,173,90,442,273,2
"8","2021/09/12 02:23",265,112,241,307,329,64,71,82,515,260,3
"9","2021/09/12 02:24",285,247,240,372,176,92,67,83,609,620,1
"10","2021/09/12 02:25",289,964,277,476,356,84,74,104,560,294,1
"11","2021/09/12 02:26",279,747,227,573,569,82,77,99,589,229,5
"12","2021/09/12 02:27",338,370,315,439,653,85,165,346,367,281,2
"13","2021/09/12 02:28",269,135,372,262,307,73,86,93,512,283,4
"14","2021/09/12 02:29",281,207,688,322,233,75,69,85,663,276,2
```

I wish to build a dictionary "tuples" content as follow :
In facts, i need to write the header of each column with the value of each time, with the date convert to epoch time:

"2021/09/12 02:16" = epoch 1631405760

```
 tuples.append(('perf.type.serial.object.00:00:00.TOTAL_IOPS', (1631405760 ,235)))
 tuples.append(('perf.type.serial.object.00:00:00.TOTAL_IOPS', (1631405820 ,364)))
...
 tuples.append(('perf.type.serial.object.00:00:01.TOTAL_IOPS', (1631405760 ,610)))
 tuples.append(('perf.type.serial.object.00:00:01.TOTAL_IOPS', (1631405820 ,210)))
```

I'm able to list the header, but i don't know how to keep the date and value for each

```
    import csv
    
        def read_csv(file_path):
           with open(file_path, 'rt') as f:
               csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        
               for line in csv_reader:
                   print(line)                  
           tuples.append(('perf.type.serial.object.header.col.TOTAL_IOPS', (1631405760 ,235))) ?


read_csv('my.csv')
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: pandas data frame would be well suited here. You can read csv as dataframe, and then iterate the column you need to. pls let us know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: Yes, i see that panda libs can perform this kind of read, but i never use panda...

Comment: pls see my response as answer and let me know if you would  like me to add more info!

Comment: Many thanks simpleApp! it's exactly what i need.

Comment: at the end, i got these values: ('perf.type.serial.object.epoch.TOTAL_IOPS', (1639472400, 1639472400)) ?

Comment: you could replace `list(df.columns)[2:]` with `list(df.columns)[2:-1]`, so new column(`epoch`) is not part of the processing.

Comment: Great, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("raw_data.csv") # read the csv
```

2. Add the new column value, please tweak to your epoch logic.

```
import time, os
date_pattern='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'
df['epoch'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(time.mktime(time.strptime(row.time,date_pattern))), axis=1) # create epoch as a column
df
```

3. save the data in the list or any ds as needed.

```
tuples_saved=[] # data will be saved in a list
formated_str='perf.type.serial.object.00:00:00.TOTAL_IOPS'
for each_column in list(df.columns)[2:]:
    for e in zip(list(df['epoch']),list(df[each_column])):
        #print(f"perf.type.serial.object.{each_column}.TOTAL_IOPS",e)
        tuples_saved.append((f"perf.type.serial.object.{each_column}.TOTAL_IOPS",e))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        dict_from_csv={rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in csv_reader}
print(dict_from_csv)
```